# Extracting text just before a table

Tags: r, xml, parsing, datatables

I would like to extract the sub-heading just one line or two before a table from a xml file. As an example, on this webpage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_database

There are several tables, which I was able to extract with their headers using library(xml) and R code provided by https://rud.is/b/2015/08/23/using-r-to-get-data-out-of-word-docs/

Now, I would like to index just one row above the table and get the corresponding text. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the rvest package to get the first paragraph in the web page:

[selectorgadget](https://selectorgadget.com) can help identify the right element name for the html page.

```r
library(rvest)

read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_database") |> 
  html_element("p:nth-child(1)") |> 
  html_text2()

#> [1] "A cost database is a computerized database of cost estimating information, which is normally used with construction estimating software to support the formation of cost estimates. A cost database may also simply be an electronic reference of cost data."
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To get the first paragraph of a Word document:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)

# Create table
df <- tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2,
  "a", 1,
  "b", 2
)

# Create Word doc with para and table
example_doc <- read_docx() |> 
  body_add_par("Some text.") |> 
  body_add_table(df, style = "table_template")

# Save Word doc
print(example_doc, target = "example.docx")

# Read the doc
content <- read_docx("example.docx") |> 
  docx_summary()

# Get the text before the table
content |> 
  filter(doc_index == 1) |> 
  select(text)
#>         text
#> 1 Some text.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>